# Routing inconsistency in codeigniter - incorrect route coded

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I have the following code in my routes.php in a codeigniter project.

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['(:any)'] = 'login/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'login/view';
```

The following url takes me to the about page correctly (which is located here: views/pages/about.php)

```
http://localhost:1234/ciblog/index.php/pages/view/about
```

Also **http://localhost:1234/ciblog/index.php/news** takes me to the news page correctly which is located here: views/news/index.php

I would like, however, **http://localhost:1234/ciblog/index.php/about** to take me to the about page, and instead a 404 error is returned. To clarify, I don't want to have to type in the "pages/view" in the url, to get to the about page. And the same for the login page. I don't want to have to type in login/view ....to get to the login.php page.

I thought that this line code, arranged for this to be routed such that pages/view is bypassed (that is the views/pages directory) so that it goes straight to the about.php page, but clearly, I am missing some logic.

The controller for the Pages.php is as so:

```
<?php
    class Pages extends CI_Controller{
        public function view($page = 'home')
{
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
    }
```

Can someone point out what I've done wrong, but also, as an accepted answer, explain how exactly the routing works in simple terms. If I wanted to simply create a new page, and create a route (url) that allowed me to access that page from the localhost/page (i.e directly) what is the best method to do so?

For reference, a screenshot of the directory structure can be seen on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two conflicting routes `(:any)`.

```php
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'login/view/$1';
$route['login'] = 'login/view';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

During the bootstrap CI will look com `$route` array trying to find a match for the current request. If a match is found, it'll then use the corresponding value as controller/method.

---

Unless you planned to do this way, you don't need a "view" method on your controller.

You could do something like this:

```php
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
  public function index()
  {
    $data['title'] = "Home";
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
  public function about()
  {
    $data['title'] = "About";
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/about', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
}
```

So your route could be:

```
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['home'] = 'pages/home';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/home';
```

It is more verbose, but is easy to understand.

Comment: Could you explain what this does > $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; ....this should, if I'm correct, allow me to write "anything" after the localhost e.g. localhost/any ...and it should redirect to that view ...e.g localhost/any.html (if it exists). I still don't understand why the above doesn't work, even if I remove the conflicting route. Can you help me get it to work (add to your answer) with removing the conflicting route but keeping the same pattern in routing as suggested by the official docs.

Comment: The problem is explained in the very first line of the answer -"You have two conflicting routes."  Note that `$route` is an array. The second time you assign a value to `$route['login/(:any)']` you overwrite the first value you set. The same goes for `$route['default_controller']`. Only the second value - `'pages/view'` will be available when CI gets around to figuring out which controller/method to execute.